# Can't change my name after adding "color" in minecraft pe

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I learned how to add color to my minecraft name but when I tried to change it back so I could play external it wouldn't let me type in any letters or numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You should try downloading your Minecraft data on to a computer.

Delete Minecraft Pocket Edition, then wait a couple of minutes, then re-install it.

Plug your device into the computer, and put all the Minecraft data back on you device.